# How to get full size image from imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I captured an image of `2592x1936` from mobile's camera, converted it into bitmap. I displayed it my imageview as`myImageVew.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);`

after displaying this bitmap i perform some manipulation over this image(inside the imageview), now i m saving this using

```
Bitmap bitmap;
// frmCaptureThis is the root framelayout (this contains my imageview)
View v1 = frmCaptureThis; 
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

saveImgToSDcard(bitmap);
```

this is saving my image to SD card but not with the `2592x1936` resolutions, its saving my image with size equal to the imageView size (i.e 400X620). i want to save the image with original resolution i.e `2592x1936`

**EDIT**

here is my code for taking image via intent

```
// ////////// Capture Button Handler//////////////////
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                    "From your Camera");

            imageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OPEN_CAMERA);

        }
    });
```

and Here is my on Activity Result method

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String imageurl = null;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_CAMERA
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        captureFlage = true;
        relTapToCapture.setEnabled(false);
        relHeader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frmCaptureThis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtTapToCapture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);

        if (thumbnail.getWidth() > thumbnail.getHeight()) {
            // Log.i("Orientation", "LandScape");

            // thumbnail = rotateImage_90(thumbnail);
            imgCaptured.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        } else {
            // Log.i("Orientation", "Portrait");
            imgCaptured.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }

        File file = new File(imageurl);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

and here is my method for saving the image in SD card

```
public void saveImgToSDcard(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current milliseconds since 13 Oct, 2008 are :"
            + cal.getTimeInMillis());

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "brandYourImage" + cal.getTimeInMillis()
            + ".jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    try {
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    // remember close de FileOutput
    try {
        fo.close();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: 2592x1936 from mobile's camera,

Comment: add your code for getting the Image from camera and saving to the SD card.

Comment: I have the code but not right now. I will paste it tomorrow. its in my office PC. :) thanks. you shuould star this question if you think you know the answer.

Comment: @EmilAdz Please see my updated code. and sorry for pasting my code late.

Comment: @QadirHussain hi... Have you solved your problem?